# "set foo to text returned of" for numbers?

Tags: string, integer, applescript, automator

I know you can do `set foo to text returned of (display dialog "Dialog" default answer "default")`.
I've tried everything from `set foo to number returned of` or `set foo to integer returned of` but I can't seem to find the keyword for returning a number. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the text returned, and then coerce it into an integer:

```
set foo to (text returned of (display dialog "Enter a number" default answer "42")) as integer
```

or, broken up more to illustrate is:

```
display dialog "Enter a number" default answer "42"
set foo to text returned of the result
set foo to foo as integer
```

I would separate it out so you can wrap a try block around the coercion in the event that it's not a number.

```
set foo to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a number" default answer "42")
try
    set foo to foo as integer
on error err
    set foo to 0
end
```

And, here would be one way of repeatedly asking until they supply a valid number:

```
set msg to "Enter a number"
repeat
    set foo to text returned of (display dialog msg default answer "42")
    try
        set foo to foo as integer
        exit repeat
    on error err
        set msg to "That's not a valid number. Please enter a number."
    end try
end repeat
return foo
```

Comment: Still, that's a pretty stupid method. I mean, none of that is the fault of an informed person like you, but, jeez Apple.

Comment: Well, Applescript is designed for cross-functionality with other apps. The default display dialog standard addition is a bare bones option. You can not tell it to only accept integers. You'll have to code your own dialog in cocoa or other to do that.  Still, having to coerce with "(  ) as integer" is not the much to do extra.